# GIMP alternative on Android or iPad

Tags: gimp, photo-editing, android, open-source, ipad

I'm searching for an open source alternative for GIMP for an Android tablet or Apple iPad. Can anyone suggest any free apps not browser based solutions like photopea

Comment: Krita is available on the Playstore. That's probably the closest to GIMP you can get.  It's not exactly the same, more of a painting drawing app, rather than a photo editing application like GIMP

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a "shopping list" question and any answers would be A) merely opinion and B) outdated rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new GIMP app that came out on Play Store.  Here is the link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula.gimp&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).